# PHP or JavaScript issue when parsing JSON encoded PHP array into JavaScripts JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm currently making a web app for my workplace, that downloads around 40,000 rows of data from an SQL table in one go, places the data into nested PHP arrays, and then attempts to echo the JSON encoded array, where a JavaScript variable should capture the contents.

If I attempt to echo the data straight into the  tags, it works fine - everything is displayed perfectly - formatted as a JSON encoded string. If, however, I attempt to echo the data into `<script>` tags, between speech marks '' or "", it throws an error in chrome, saying 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' - and when I attempt to scroll to the end of the (very long) string, it appears to have been chopped off, only a few thousand characters in.

The string is actually 1,476,075 characters long.

How do I get around this? I'm remaking the application - it originally basically combined javascript with the SQL results whilst iterating through the results rows, but this was so slow and clunky, so I figured an easier and quicker way to move the data from PHP to JavaScript, would be with a large JSON encoded string.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

- Dan.

Comment: If it's JSON-encoded, you don't need quotes. Just drop it directly into JavaScript code in your `<script>` tags.

Comment: I'm passing it into JSON.parse() - I'm pretty sure it needs to be encapsulated in quotation marks. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: There's no need to pass it into `JSON.parse()`, that's the point - JSON syntax is valid JavaScript syntax. That's what the J in JSON stands for.

Comment: How would I capture the array that it's held in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json_encode() takes care of ALL the quoting/escaping that needs to be done:

```
<?php
    $foo = 'this is a simple string';
?>

<script>
    var foo = "<?php echo json_encode($foo); ?>"; // incorrect
    var bar = <?php echo json_encode($foo); ?>; // correct
```

The above construct would create:

```
var foo = ""this is a simple string"";
          ^--- your quote
           ^---the quote json_encode added

var bar = "this is a simple string"; // all-ok here.
```

Comment: I understand now, thank you. I've only been using JavaScript for a few months now, but I should have figured that one out. Thank you all, very much!